# how to get files out of the git tab if rstudio

Tags: git, r

I'm a doof and keep uploading .Rpoj, .Rbuildignore and .gitignore to github.  Some of these files mess with other project contributor's local repo when they pull them.  I've figure out how to fix this after I've done it but it involves so command line code:

```
git reset --hard (number of last good commit)
git push -f origin HEAD^:master
```

I prefer not to do this monkey business.  Is there a way to remove these pesky files from the git tab windows so I don't accidentally upload them anymore.  I don't even know what to search for to find an answer.

Here's a screen shot of files I need in my local repo but want to disappear out of the git tab window in RStudio.

[image]

Comment: Btw. the tags are somewhat misleading, this is a git question and not an r or rstudio question.

Comment: It is indeed...although I suspect that Tyler didn't realised that at first.

Comment: @sencarmody you are correct.  I've only recently started using git and RStudio and let's be honest here I don't understand them yet and haven't had time to explore the documentation in any detail.  Gabor, thanks.  DWin has edited the tags to reflect this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following lines to the `.gitignore` file:

```
.gitignore
.Rbuildignore
pacman.Rproj
```

Comment: No problem: this situation is exactly what .gitignore is designed to deal with.

Comment: That is very helpful information.  Probably it's in multiple places in the documentation.

Comment: It is in `man gitignore`, which describes the pattern formats for the file in detail.

Comment: @seancarmody - The only thing I find surprising about this answer is that it requires adding .gitignore to itself. How do you make sure other collaborators don't inadvertently push files you don't want if no one is really sharing the same common ignore file?

Comment: @briandk I suppose I'd turn the question around the other way: if you _did_ want to have all collborators share the same `.gitignore` file, how would you do it if `.gitignore` was automatically ignored? At least with the current behaviour it is easy to ignore `.gitignore`. The reverse set-up would not be easy to undo.